# Empty bibliography after new refsegment biblatex splitted by sections bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, splitbib

I want to create a custom article that will list various references at the end of each section. This reference list needs to be independent of each other although some cited articles may appear in each list in different order. This a MWE of my intended document

```
\begin{filecontents}{refslist.bib}
    @article{key,
        author = {author1},
        title = {title1}
    }
    @article{key2,
        author = {author2},
        title ={title2}
    }
    @article{key3,
        author = {author3},
        title ={title3}
    }
    
    @article{key4,
        author ={author4},
        title ={title4}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,style=numeric,backend=bibtex,url=true,isbn=false,sorting=none,citereset=subsection]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refslist.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Show}
This section will show a list of cited articles \cite{key,key2,key3,key4}
\subsection{References in order 1}
\printbibliography[heading=none,section=\therefsection, title={References}]

\section{Not Show}
This section will not show a list of cited articles \cite{key2,key3,key3,key} \therefsection
\newrefsection
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\section{Show Again}
\newrefsegment
This section will show a list of cited articles in different order \therefsection \cite{key4,key3,key2}
\subsection{References in order 2}
\printbibliography[heading=none,section=1, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

The output of the file after compiling it is not the desired output.

[image]

If I change the backend to biber as suggested on similar questions doesn't work it gets even worse not a single citing label is recognized.

[image]

The desired output should be like this (I create this by hand )

[image]

According to my log file, after line 39 where I declare a new refsegment  all citation keys after that line become undefined. Thus, line 40 \printbibliograph produces an empty bibliography.

Is there a workaround this? I am working on Win TeXstudio 2.10.4 and on Mac TeXshop 3.61 (doesn't make any difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all advanced features are supported with `backend=bibtex,`. For full support of all `biblatex`  features you need to use `backend=biber,`. Note that you then need to compile your document with Biber and  not with BibTeX (or you need to tell your editor about it: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)).

Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  defernumbers=true,
  citereset=subsection,
  url=true,isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author = {author1},
  title  = {title1}
}
@article{key2,
  author = {author2},
  title  = {title2}
}
@article{key3,
  author = {author3},
  title  = {title3}
} 
@article{key4,
  author = {author4},
  title  = {title4}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Show}
This section will show a list of cited articles \cite{key,key2,key3,key4}
\subsection{References in order 1}
\printbibliography[heading=none,section=\therefsection, title={References}]

\section{Not Show}
This section will not show a list of cited articles
\cite{key2,key3,key3,key} \therefsection



\newrefsection
\section{Show Again}

This section will show a list of cited articles in different order
\therefsection \cite{key4,key3,key2}
\subsection{References in order 2}
\printbibliography[heading=none,section=1, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

for me, which looks pretty similar to what you want.

(I removed the `\newrefsegment`. It didn't do anything useful here.)

Comment: Even when backend=biber and  manually compiling with biber  I am still unable to get the desired output

Comment: @JaredLo Can you get Biber to compile https://gist.github.com/moewew/3db5241d57a4616580d319d83247cbfe to the expected output?

Comment: I think this is a particular error on my package installation. Or an outdated version of Biber. But on top on changing to biber my compilation I needed to add an extra \newrefsection at the end of the first \printbibliography to get things working

Comment: @JaredLo It's possible that older versions of `biblatex` had a bug there. But if you have to add a `\newrefsection` at that point, the citations following it are independent from the `\printbibliography` in the previous section. So you cannot really expect usable output. I strongly suggest you update your system. I just double checked: With a current version of `biblatex` you  get the intended output.